# how to search elements in a 2d array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have a 2d char array and I'm trying to find a specific character using recursion.

```
public class Test {

char arry [][] = {{'1',' ','B'},
                  {'C','K','M'},
                  {'H','R','P'}
};

public Test(){
    recursion(0,0,arry[0][0]);

}
private void recursion(int row, int col, char c) {
    if(c==' '){
        System.out.print("Location: " + row + " " + col );
    }else
    {
        if(col+1<arry[0].length){
            recursion(row,col,c);
        }
                    //System.out.print(arry[0][1]);

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Test();
}

}
```

but this is giving me a stack overflow. how can I find an element in a 2d array using recursion.

Comment: Your method calls itself with exactly the same argument values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your if statement isn't being executed properly. You are checking to check `if c == "  "`, though I think you meant it to check `if array[row][col]==c`. Also, it seems like you never actually increment the values of `row` and `col`, so the recursion continuously happens on itself. Since the recursion values never change, and the check can never be true, this will eventually lead to a stackoverflow.

Try something along these lines:

```
private void recursion(int row, int col, char c) {
    if(array[row][col]==c){
        System.out.print("Location: " + row + " " + col );
    } else {
        if(col+1<array[0].length){
            recursion(row,col+1,c);
        } else if(row + 1<array[1].length){
            recursion(row+1,0,c);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Does not exist");
            //System.out.print(arry[0][1]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You method is calling itself with same values all the time.

```
recursion(row,col,c);
```

Update your value then send it to the method again. so it could look for another element in your array

For example:

```
recursion(row,++col,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void recursion(int row, int col, char c) {
if(c==' '){
    System.out.print("Location: " + row + " " + col );
}else
{
    if(col+1<arry[0].length){
        recursion(row,col+1,c);
    }
    else
         recursion(row+1, 0, c)
                //System.out.print(arry[0][1]);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to search for a value in a 2D-Array would be to start at (0, 0) and scan through the entire column before advancing to the next row. When a value matches what you are looking for, return that location.

Here is an example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Find2D {
    public static int[] search(char[][] arr, char ch, int row, int col) {
        if (arr[row][col] == ch) {
            return new int[] { row, col };
        } else {
            if (col + 1 < arr[0].length) {
                return search(arr, ch, row, col + 1);
            } else if (row + 1 < arr[1].length) {
                return search(arr, ch, row + 1, 0);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static int[] search(char[][] arr, char ch) {
        return search(arr, ch, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void printr(int[] result) {
        System.out.println("Location: " + Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char arr[][] = {
            { '1', ' ', 'B' },
            { 'C', 'K', 'M' },
            { 'H', 'R', 'P' }
        };

        printr(search(arr, arr[0][0])); // [0, 0]
        printr(search(arr, 'M'));       // [1, 2]
        printr(search(arr, 'x'));       // null
    }
}
```