# Recursively search 2D array without row and column indexing in method?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, indexing

I'm currently working on a homework assignment and I'm really stuck on this idea of recursively searching an array without a row and column to index. I believe I can use helper methods but I'm new to recursion and find it a little confusing. This is the method that I'm not allowed to change (for the purpose of the assignment)

```
public Couple search(int[][]array, int element){

}
```

I'm also provided an inner class from the instructor. We haven't learned anything about inner classes, however, the appear to be nothing special. It is basic and I doesn't do anything special so I won't include the code unless there is something that is needed that I don't know. (I don't want to be cheating and I want to more-or-less figure it out too).

```
private class Couple{
  // declaration of (int) row and (int) col

  public Couple(row, col){
  // this.row = row
  // col = col
  }

  public String toString(){
  // returns string
  }

}
```

EDIT: I also can't use any loops

Comment: I think you would need to pass state through the recursion about what your position is in the array.  But I also would not use recursion to search a 2D array in Java.

Comment: @Joe Are you sure the method signature you stated for `search()` is correct? Shouldn't it be `public Couple search(int[][]array, int element, Couple couple)` ?

Comment: @Joe With what as given , it cannot be done unless you are allowed to access some static variables to record the current `row` and `col`. Currently, there is no way to reduce the problem to reach your goal for the subsequent recursive calls because the array will always be the same array and element will always be the same element value. The only way to do it will be what user `Manuel Seiche ` stated, which I will be surprised if your school is expecting that because it defeats the purpose of your method signature restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** removed for-loop, added recursive Example

example for recursive subroutine

```
public class FindElement2DimArrayExample {
    private class Couple {
        private int row;
        private int col;

        public Couple(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "[" + row + ", " + col + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        System.out.println(new FindElement2DimArrayExample().search(array, 5));
    }

    public Couple search(int[][] array, int element) {
        return searchRecursively(array, element, 0, 0);
    }

    public Couple searchRecursively(int[][] array, int element, int actualRow, int actualCol) {
        if (array.length <= actualRow) {
            return null;
        } else if (array[actualRow].length <= actualCol) {
            return searchRecursively(array, element, actualRow + 1, 0);
        } else if (array[actualRow][actualCol] == element) {
            return new Couple(actualRow, actualCol);
        } else {
            return searchRecursively(array, element, actualRow, actualCol + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not the best way to search a 2D Array, but if it is your assignment, you may try to realize it via the "Divide and Conquer" approach: Split the array into two parts and recursively call the method again on these two parts until you found the element.

Maybe this is useful for you: [how to search elements in a 2d array using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434762/how-to-search-elements-in-a-2d-array-using-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify that you cant write some other method...
So i'd write another search method with signature:

private Couple search(Couple couple, int[][] array, int element)

Containing the following:

```
            static private Couple search(Couple couple, int[][] array, int element) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Checking:" + couple + (array[couple.col][couple.row]));
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {}
                if (couple.col>=array.length) return search(new Couple(0,couple.row+1),array,element);
                if (couple.row>=array[0].length) return new Couple(-1,-1);
                if (array[couple.row][couple.col] == element) return couple;
                else return search(new Couple(couple.col+1,couple.row),array,element);
            }
```

and call it from your other method by:

```
static public Couple search(int[][] array, int element) {
    return search(new Couple(0,0),array,element);
}
```

That should do the trick.
Other then that (if you cant write additional method) then I'd use a stack.

full code:

```
public class NewClass1 {

static class Couple {
    int col, row;

public Couple(int col, int row) {
    this.col = col;
    this.row = row;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Couple{" + "col=" + col + ", row=" + row + '}';
}


}    
static int[][] getArr(int nx, int ny) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] arr = new int[nx][ny];
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand.nextInt(90)+10;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

static void print(int [][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ";");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

static public Couple search(int[][] array, int element) {
    return search(new Couple(0,0),array,element);
}

static private Couple search(Couple couple, int[][] array, int element) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Checking:" + couple + (array[couple.col][couple.row]));
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {}
    if (couple.col>=array.length) return search(new Couple(0,couple.row+1),array,element);
    if (couple.row>=array[0].length) return new Couple(-1,-1);
    if (array[couple.row][couple.col] == element) return couple;
    else return search(new Couple(couple.col+1,couple.row),array,element);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = getArr(10,10);
    print(arr);
    System.out.println(search(arr,11));

}
}
```

Comment: `EDIT: I also can't use any loops`

Comment: @user3437460 there were no for loops in the search, only for filling and printing the arr (i assumed no loops in the search is what you need). Well, seems like you found the solution that's working for you. Hope you'll get a good mark! Best regards.

Comment: I am afraid I got the wrong person. I am not OP. Cheers.